# cross domain issues prevent action when reload parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm  trying to reload the parent page from another domain. I achieved the reload on parent page when closing the child, but once I reload, the action on `onclick` event triggers again. My question is how can I prevent `window.open` once it reloads?

This is the code:

```
// here I've added `return false` but it fails to prevent the popup 
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  onclick="return myopen('https://www.example.org/applicant/getdrivers?ApplicantId=15647&type=0', 'VieworUploadDocs','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,position=center,width=700px,height=850px');return false;" Text="Click Here" />
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         //open window
         var myWindow = null;
         var myTimer = null;

         myopen = function (url) {
             myWindow = open(url, 'VieworUploadDocs', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,position=center,width=700px,height=850px');
             myTimer = setInterval(function (e) {
                 if (myWindow == null || myWindow.closed) {

                     alert('Please wait while page loads.');
                     location.reload();
                     clearInterval(myTimer);
                     e.stopPropagation();
                 }
             }, 5000);
         }
         </script>
```

I've also tried putting this in my code:

```
return false;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: javascript can not (easily) run between pages that are not on the same domain

Comment: @JaromandaX then how does the CDN hosted scripts (e.g JQuery) run with no trouble?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes sir.. i searched alot on how to achieved on how to reload the parent page from different domain and end up on that.. ive also tried using window.postMessage but its not working for me.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you wish to achieve ... if it's communication between javascript on pages on different domains, **both** need to use `window.postMessage` "co-operatively" ... i.e., you can't make one page post a message and without changes make the other page do your bidding

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq - who mentioned anything about where the scripts are **hosted** ... I thought the question was about javascript on one page telling javascript on the other page what to do

Comment: @JaromandaX  theres 2 scenarios that i want to achieve first, i need to reload the parent page from child page that is on different domain. second is, i need to prevent the event action when it  reloads. the action that i want to prevent is the click event that opens the child window page.

Comment: @A.Wolff what do you mean change popup sourcecode?

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand what is the problem of this user, maybe he wants to refresh the parent window when the popup is closed but everytime the parent page refreshed, it keeps the event of opening the popup and he wants it to stop propagating

Comment: @EnriqueGil Sorry, i misunderstood issue here